# Wondering what the word "glamour" refers to in this context

Tags: word-meaning

> Actress Sharon Stone brought **her brand of glamour** to Cannes on Wednesday, but apart from the expected red carpet-full of stars there was also a touch of controversy.
>   When French Director Michel Hazanavicius’s film ‘The Search’ was screened it was greeted with both boos and cheers.

Source: http://euronews.com/2014/05/22/controversy-in-cannes-as-the-film-the-search-is-booed-and-cheered/

I am wondering if is literary talking about a new product being advertised at cannes film festival with brand "Stone" , for example, or it is talking figuratively about her beauty !

Answer (score 1):

The phrase refers to the particular style of beauty possessed by Sharon Stone. One way to detect this is by observing that *glamour* is a quality, not a class of product. It also implies that her type of *glamour* is special or particular, and not possessed or displayed by others.

In the high end clothing and fashion industry, it's common practice to name a product line after the designer; e.g. Calvin Klein. I suspect this turn of phrase (the use of *her brand* meaning something other a literal product) emerged as a result of this.

Answer (score 1):

It's the glamor, *the Sharon Stone way.* Her style in that sense is unique.

*brand of something* means that particular type of something. [As in OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/brand_1)

> an unorthodox brand of humour [-the humor in an unorthodox way].